# How to serialize in jackson json null string to empty string

Tags: json, jackson

I need jackson json (1.8) to serialize a java NULL string to an empty string. How do you do it?
Any help or suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Take a look to this article: http://magicmonster.com/kb/prg/java/spring/webmvc/jackson_custom.html

Answer (score 11):

See the [docs on Custom Serializers](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonHowToCustomSerializers); there's an example of exactly this, works for me.

In case the docs move let me paste the relevant answer:

> **Converting null values to something else**
>
> (like empty Strings)
>
> If you want to output some other JSON value instead of null (mainly
>   because some other processing tools prefer other constant values --
>   often empty String), things are bit trickier as nominal type may be
>   anything; and while you could register serializer for `Object.class`, it
>   would not be used unless there wasn't more specific serializer to use.
>
> But there is specific concept of "null serializer" that you can use as
>   follows:
>
> ```
> // Configuration of ObjectMapper:
> {
>     // First: need a custom serializer provider
>    StdSerializerProvider sp = new StdSerializerProvider();
>    sp.setNullValueSerializer(new NullSerializer());
>    // And then configure mapper to use it
>    ObjectMapper m = new ObjectMapper();
>    m.setSerializerProvider(sp);
> }
>
> // serialization as done using regular ObjectMapper.writeValue()
>
> // and NullSerializer can be something as simple as:
> public class NullSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Object>
> {
>    public void serialize(Object value, JsonGenerator jgen,
> SerializerProvider provider)
>        throws IOException, JsonProcessingException
>    {
>        // any JSON value you want...
>        jgen.writeString("");
>    }
> }
> ```

Comment: Seems to be this one: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonHowToCustomSerializers

Comment: Thanks @streetturtle, that's it.

Comment: what about converting non-existent attributes that are String type so they are empty string to.  This only seemed to work if something was null.