# Jackson: deserializing null Strings as empty Strings

Tags: java, null, jackson

I have the following class, that is mapped by Jackson (simplified version):

```
public class POI {
    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String name;
}
```

In some cases the server returns `"name": null` and I would like to then set name to empty Java String.

Is there any Jackson annotation or should I just check for the null inside my getter and return empty string if the property is `null`?

Comment: Ok this is a duplicate :-)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5782284/how-to-serialize-in-jackson-json-null-string-to-empty-string

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can either set it in the default constructor, or on declaration:

```
public class POI {
    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String name; 

    public POI() {
        name = "";
    }
}
```

OR

```
public class POI {
    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String name = "";
}
```

Comment: Great answer. ¿Any solution when the no parameter constructor is managed by Lombok?

Answer (score 29):

Jackson 2.9 actually offers a new mechanism not yet mentioned: use of `@JsonSetter` for properties, and its equivalent "Config Overrides" for types like `String.class`.
Longer explanation included in

https://medium.com/@cowtowncoder/jackson-2-9-features-b2a19029e9ff

but gist is that you can either mark field (or setter) like so:

```
@JsonSetter(nulls=Nulls.AS_EMPTY) public String stringValue;
```

or configure mapper to do the same for all `String` value properties:

```
mapper.configOverride(String.class)
 .setSetterInfo(JsonSetter.Value.forValueNulls(Nulls.AS_EMPTY));
```

both of which would convert incoming `null` into empty value, which for Strings is "".

This also works for `Collection`s and `Map`s as expected.

Comment: Setting `@JsonSetter(nulls = Nulls.AS_EMPTY)` worked for me when API could either send "null" as a value or not send the field at all. In both cases it was mapped to an empty string. Exactly what I needed, thanks!

Comment: For collections: this doesn't work for **missing** properties, at least with Jackson 2.11.3. What does work when deserializing both explicit null values **and** missing properties is a final collection field initialized to an empty collection, with a getter only, and specifying `Nulls.SKIP` - either on the field itself or by configuring the mapper as specified in this answer.

Comment: @YanivNahoum correct, properties without incoming values are not handled, with the exception of Constructor-passed (`@JsonCreator`) case in which some value must be provided . So you are correct in that this is one way to work around the limitation.

Answer (score 17):

Again, this answer is for the **SO users** who happen to stumble upon this thread.

While the accepted answer stands accepted and valid in all its sense - it did not help me in the case where the decision to set `null` string values to `empty` string came only after we made our services available to `iOS` clients.

So, around 30-40 pojo's(increasing) and initializing them while instantiating the object in question or at the point of declaration was too much.

Here's how we did it.

```
public class CustomSerializerProvider extends DefaultSerializerProvider {

    public CustomSerializerProvider() {
        super();
    }

    public CustomSerializerProvider(CustomSerializerProvider provider, SerializationConfig config,
            SerializerFactory jsf) {
        super(provider, config, jsf);
    }

    @Override
    public CustomSerializerProvider createInstance(SerializationConfig config, SerializerFactory jsf) {
        return new CustomSerializerProvider(this, config, jsf);
    }

    @Override
    public JsonSerializer<Object> findNullValueSerializer(BeanProperty property) throws JsonMappingException {
        if (property.getType().getRawClass().equals(String.class))
            return Serializers.EMPTY_STRING_SERIALIZER_INSTANCE;
        else
            return super.findNullValueSerializer(property);
    }
}
```

And, the serializer

```
public class Serializers extends JsonSerializer<Object> {
    public static final JsonSerializer<Object> EMPTY_STRING_SERIALIZER_INSTANCE = new EmptyStringSerializer();

    public Serializers() {}

    @Override
    public void serialize(Object o, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        jsonGenerator.writeString("");
    }

    private static class EmptyStringSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Object> {
        public EmptyStringSerializer() {}

        @Override
        public void serialize(Object o, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider)
                throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
            jsonGenerator.writeString("");
        }
    }
}
```

And, then set the serializer in the ObjectMapper. (***Jackson 2.7.4***)

```
ObjectMapper nullMapper = new ObjectMapper();
nullMapper.setSerializerProvider(new CustomSerializerProvider());
```

Hoping, this will save someone some time.

Comment: **SO users** means what?

Comment: `stackoverflow` -> `SO`

Comment: i see, thk u answer

Answer (score 12):

A simple solution using no Jackson specialities: Write a Getter for name which returns an empty String instead of null as Jackson uses those to serialize.

```
public String getName() {
  return name != null ? name : "";
}
```

Another way would be to write a custom deserializer. Look here: http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHowToCustomSerializers

Answer (score 1):

In case you are looking for a global solution for spring boot, you can configure the `ObjectMapper`

```
@Configuration
public class JacksonConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder mapperBuilder) {
        DefaultSerializerProvider sp = new DefaultSerializerProvider.Impl();
        sp.setNullValueSerializer(new JsonSerializer<Object>() {
            public void serialize(Object value, JsonGenerator jgen,
                                  SerializerProvider provider)
                    throws IOException, JsonProcessingException
            {
                jgen.writeString("");
            }
        });
        ObjectMapper mapper = mapperBuilder.build();
        mapper.setSerializerProvider(sp);
        return mapper;
    }

}
```