# JSON arrays and Scala Seq

Tags: json, scala, deserialization

I have scala class like `class A(b:Seq[String])`

My problem is when I deserialize it from text which have no `b` field my class contains `null`. It is possible to force deserealizer to fill with empty `Seq`?

I use `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper` with `com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule`.

**EDIT:**
I want solution that fix all such fields without explicitly mentioning full list of them. Ir changing all declarations.

Comment: Are you open to using alternative JSON libraries?

Comment: Yes. I can use alternative library.

Answer (score 5):

This is not currently supported by Jackson, unfortunately.

You can see the relevant GitHub ticket here: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/347

Your best bet is to map `null` into an empty `Seq` in the class constructor or in an accessor method:

```
class A(_b: Seq[String]) {
  val b = _b match {
    case null => Nil
    case bs => bs
  }
}
```

(See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/20655330/8261 for other options)

Comment: This solution require to make changes for each field of type `Seg[?]`. I want to fix problem in one place.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Spray JSON, then a simple example which doesn't handle the absence of the `b` field would look like:

```
import spray.json._

case class A(b: Seq[String])

object Protocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
  implicit def aFormat = jsonFormat1(A)
}

import Protocol._

val str1 = """{ "b" : [] }""""
val str2 = """{ "b" : ["a", "b", "c"] }""""
val str3 = """{}"""
str1.parseJson.convertTo[A]//successful
str2.parseJson.convertTo[A]//successful
str3.parseJson.convertTo[A]//Deserialization error
```

In Spray JSON, this can be solved by writing a more detailed protocol format for class A:

```
import spray.json._

case class A(b: Seq[String])

object Protocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {

  implicit object aFormat extends RootJsonFormat[A] {
    override def write(obj: A): JsValue = JsObject("b" -> obj.b.toJson)

    override def read(json: JsValue): A = json match {
      //Case where the object has exactly one member, 'b'
      case JsObject(map) if map.contains("b") && map.size == 1 => A(map("b").convertTo[Seq[String]])
      //Case where the object has no members
      case JsObject(map) if map.isEmpty => A(Seq())
      //Any other json value, which cannot be converted to an instance of A
      case _ => deserializationError("Malformed")
    }
  }
}

import Protocol._

val str1 = """{ "b" : [] }""""
val str2 = """{ "b" : ["a", "b", "c"] }""""
val str3 = """{}"""
str1.parseJson.convertTo[A]//successful
str2.parseJson.convertTo[A]//successful
str3.parseJson.convertTo[A]//successful
```

Comment: This solution requires explicitly specify all fields of `Seq[?]` type. I have lot of them and want all of them behave this way.

Comment: Can you give a concrete example? Is it many case classes or one class with many members of type seq?

Comment: Both of it. I have several case classes with multiple `Seq` field in each.

Comment: What if I have `case class A(b: Seq[String])` and `case class B(c: Seq[String])` and I am trying to deserialize `{ }` how would I know which case class to target?

Comment: I don't know how jackson handle this situation, but how it relates to my question? Same problem appear even without `Seq` field

Comment: It relates because the way you want to handle that situation affects the solution. For example if you know which class you are trying to deserialize to each time, situation is easier.

Comment: Yes I know what class I desalinize

Comment: If you're able to alter your case classes, the simplest solution is to use `case class A(b: Option[Seq[String]])` then Spray Json will handle the situation no problem.

Comment: If i should change all declarations I better change it right way. Like Rich suggest

Comment: In Scala the idiomatic way of handling data is using Option, not using null. Also for this kind of data structure, a case class would be more idiomatic for scala. With Rich's method you lose some of the benefits of case classes such as generated apply and unapply methods

Comment: Meant to say, "handling Optional data"

Comment: I agree, but I already have `Seq` so no `null` expected. My actual problem is that i got `null` and I want empty `Seq`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem deserializing String arrays with jackson, and found that jackson apparently (have not tried yet) fixed this in jackson-module 2.1.2. It might work for Seq.
https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-scala/issues/48

Comment: We use jackson-module-scala_2.11 version 2.6.1