# Jackson Deserialization of all empty Strings to null in class

Tags: java, jackson

I have multiple POJOs, for some of them I would like 
to deserialize all empty Strings to `null`.

Is there a way (annotation maybe?) for me 
to tell Jackson which POJOs should deserialize 
all empty Strings to `null`,
and which shouldn't?

Not a duplicate, i'm looking for a solution which works on a class, not individual fields

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to deserialize a blank JSON string value to null for java.lang.String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30841981/how-to-deserialize-a-blank-json-string-value-to-null-for-java-lang-string)

Comment: add this property in object mapper http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationFeature.html#ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT

Comment: @Deadpool doesn't map empty Strings to null unfortunately

Comment: can you show your pojo class @heycaptain

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jackson: deserializing null Strings as empty Strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20654810/jackson-deserializing-null-strings-as-empty-strings)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a serializer as follows:

```java
public class EmptyStringAsNullDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<String> {

    @Override
    public String deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, 
                              DeserializationContext deserializationContext) 
                              throws IOException {

        String value = jsonParser.getText();
        if (value == null || value.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

Add it to a `Module` and then register the `Module` to your `ObjectMapper`:

```java
SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
module.addDeserializer(String.class, new EmptyStringAsNullDeserializer());

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.registerModule(module);
```

Comment: i added an if in the mapper, so the module would only be registered for specific POJOs, thank you @cassiomolin