# How to render null elements in List as empty in @ResponseBody?

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc

How can I render a `null` element of a list as *empty* element in a `json` `POST` response?

```
@PostMapping("/")
@ResponseBody
public MyRsp test() {
    MyRsp rps = new MyRsp();
    rsp.setList(Arrays.asList("one", "two", null, "four");
    return rsp;
```

}

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
public class MyRsp {
    @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
    private List<String> list;
}
```

Result:

```
{
   list: [
     "one",
     "two",
     null,
     "four"
   ]
}
```

I'm already using the following property:

`spring.jackson.default-property-inclusion=non_null`.

What else could I do?

Comment: What is `<empty>` in JSON?

Comment: I just ment to write: it should just render as an empty element. like: `one, two, , four`.

Comment: The linked question advises the use of `@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)`. I tried it, but did not work. Especially the propert state above `non_null` should already handle this. And indeed it works for `XML` responses, but not for `JSON`.

Comment: Your "empty element" is invalid JSON syntax...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12934045/null-values-as-empty-strings-when-using-responsebody-annotation

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto well how do I then represent "non existing" elements inside a collection in `json`? Or is `null` indeed the proper representation to set missing elements in a collection at a specific index.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_datatypes.asp

Comment: This is a `List<String>` and you want the corresponding JSON array to have an empty string in that position instead of `null`?

Comment: If a `""` is acceptable instead of `null`, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5868683/592355) might help!

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis exactly.

Comment: have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21120999/representing-null-in-json